# Gradle doesn't resolve dependencies conflict between local aar and remote repos (Maven, Google, etc.)

Tags: android, gradle

I want to ask a question regarding Gradle dependency resolution since I couldn't find it anywhere else except this [Gradle forums answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/resolve-gradle-transitive-dependency-conflict-with-file-system-libs-ie-not-maven-ivy/4513). But since it was in 2012, I want to confirm again if that is still a case.

So the problem is that if I have a local aar (a fat-aar) which includes library A, and the app that uses the aar (from a local dir) also include library A as direct dependency, there will be an error at compile time regarding "Duplicate class" or "Duplicate entry". Is it true that:

> Conflict resolution only works when you are using dependency repositories (local or remote), because the metadata is necessary.
> If you’re just pulling jar files from a directory, then no conflict resolution happens.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that: "Conflict resolution only works when you are using dependency repositories (local or remote), because the metadata is necessary. If you’re just pulling jar files from a directory, then no conflict resolution happens."

Yes, that is still true. AARs are a bundle of code and resources. The fact that the AAR may be "fat" and contain stuff from a bunch of other libraries is lost. And, as such, Gradle (nor any other build system) is going to be able to do anything about conflicts between contents within the AAR and other libraries that you may be pulling in.

Comment: Tks a lot for your answer